# Calculate time between two times Android

Tags: android, time

basically i have one time

```
currentTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

and i want to calculate how much time has past since currentTime.
any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your currentTime as above will be a String, so difficult to work with.

If you use a Date object instead:

```
Date interestingDate = new Date();
```

then you can find the different in milliseconds between the actual current date and interestingDate by doing:

```
(new Date()).getTime() - interestingDate.getTime()
```

Also check out the Time class which you could use instead of the Date class.