# Time Difference Calcuation, android

Tags: android, time, difference

I am developing alarm application where multiple alarm will fire on their selected time. Now problem is that I want to calculate the time difference between current time and the alarm time (which user has selected). How can I calculate the time difference between the current time and the alarm time selected by user without using threads. Is there any time difference method which directly calculates the time?

Comment: Convert the 2 times into `long` and make some subtraction.

Comment: thats the obvious one #enzokie but i just found what i was searching.. thanks anyway... here is easy way to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352031/calculate-time-between-two-times-android

Comment: That's just the same approach that I am saying a while ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two times android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908738/calculate-difference-between-two-times-android)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the difference between two times.

```
try {
    Date _day = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(nowTime);
    Date day = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(alarmTime);

    double diff = day.getTime() - _day.getTime() ;

    double totalMinuts = diff / (60 * 1000);
    double leftMinutsAfterHours = totalMinuts % 60;
    double totalHours = (totalMinuts - leftMinutsAfterHours) / 60;

    double leftHoursAfterDays = totalHours % 24;
    double totalDays = (totalHours - leftHoursAfterDays) / 24;

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank vidulaJ. this is the best solution so far i have found. i have implemented and its working fine.

Comment: Great! Glad to know!

Answer (score 0):

Convert time to Calander object

If you are using TimePickerDialog then.

```
Calander c=Calander.getinstance();
```

set hours and minuits

then take the millis.

then take the diffenece;

```
long differnce=pickedTimeInMillis- currentTimeInMillis;

long diffenceInSeconds=diffenrce/1000;
int differnceInMin=deffernce/(1000*60)
int differnceInHour=deffernce/(1000*60*60)
```

> Or you can do without taking millis

```
Calander currentTime=Calander.getinstance();
hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
Calander selectedTime=selectedTimeFromCalander;

int differnce=selectedTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)-hour
```

Comment: Please check . i didnt test it , just wrote only. Take absolute value and the hour is in 12 hour format so you want to check it with Am or Pm